# Allah name in clouds is Allah's miracle or are a part of random design?

Tags: allah, names, miracles

We can see sometimes that cloud take  shape of Allah's name . But I am curious to know whether they are really Allah's miracle? Or in sense of mathematics it was a random design ( since clouds are free to take any shape,and out to millions of shapes there is a probability of formation of Allah's name). Same things happens when there is Allah's name on fish/goat or any other thing which has high probability of generating random designs.

[image]

Are they really message from allah then what allah wants us to show from these?

Comment: If clouds *never* remotely resembled 'Allah' in Arabic then *that* would be miraculous.

Comment: my personal opinion. Allah doesn't need to write his name on any animal or cloud or anything to prove himself or do miracles like these. Look around, and you will see Allah's miracle everywhere.

Comment: If you looked at it from a different location, it would be just clouds. Also, the arabic letters are human made, so it's just a random match.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That there is a sky with clouds moving around in it.  Allah's miracle:

> He created the heavens without pillars that you see and has cast into the earth firmly set mountains, lest it should shift with you, and dispersed therein from every creature. And We sent down rain from the sky and made grow therein [plants] of every noble kind. -- [Qur'an 31:10](https://quran.com/31:10)
>
> Do you not see that Allah drives clouds? Then He brings them together, then He makes them into a mass, and you see the rain emerge from within it. And He sends down from the sky, mountains [of clouds] within which is hail, and He strikes with it whom He wills and averts it from whom He wills. The flash of its lightening almost takes away the eyesight. -- [Qur'an 24:43](https://quran.com/24:43)

That you're alive and have the ability to see the sky.  Allah's miracle:

> And He is the one who gave you life; then He causes you to die and then will [again] give you life. Indeed, mankind is ungrateful. -- [Qur'an 22:66](https://quran.com/22:66)
>
> And Allah has extracted you from the wombs of your mothers not knowing a thing, and He made for you hearing and vision and intellect that perhaps you would be grateful. -- [Qur'an 16:78](https://quran.com/16:78)

That some clusters of water vapour in the sky approximately resemble the short word Allah (الله)...?  I do not think it's befitting to attribute something so meagre as one of God's miracles.

It's also risky to value these things highly, because clouds also randomly form non-Islamic shapes, e.g. a crucifix.  Patterns will also randomly appear in mediums that would not be considered appropriate (e.g. birthmarks on pigs, a splattering of urine on the bathroom floor).

If you look at enough data you will find patterns, regardless of whether or not the patterns are meaningful.  How many clouds does one have to inspect before discovering one that resembled Allah in Arabic?  In science, we use [statistical significance testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) to filter out what could happen just by chance.  Perceiving familiar patterns in randomness is called [pareidolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia) in psychology.

Basically, it's best not to take these things too serious, saying "oh, that's cute" and move on.

Comment: see this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7KMJX9E2HQ
active the english subtitle ! :)

Answer (score 4):

Definition of miracle:

> A miracle is an event **not explicable by natural or scientific laws.**
>   Such an event may be attributed to a supernatural being (a deity),
>   magic, a miracle worker, a saint or a religious leader.

Formation of Allah's name in clouds, trees, fishes, goats etc can be explained by scientific laws. **Therefore, they are not miracles.**

Answer (score -5):

look i dont know how to explain it.
our prophet is muhammad and he is the last prophet until now but its doest mean who worships islam ignore other religios.
new prophet continues the unfinished job of the prophet before him.
Allah is great and deserves all the great name's.
God,Dios... and too many diferent name's in diferent languages.
seeing allah name in sky is just miracle for us because we are the ones who understand it and seeing God name in sky is miracle for those who christian.

the point is god,allah,dios... loves anybody with any religios so when u saw allah or god or other name's in sky that's a miracle in your heart if you want to look at it by sciense its just a well shaped cloud not anymore.

sorry my english is not verygood.

Comment: "the point is god/allah/dios... loves anybody with any religios so when u saw allah" there's agreement that that's false, also there's explicit texts contradicting this view.

Comment: "*our prophet is muhammad and he is the last prophet until now but its doesn't mean who worships islam ignore other religions. new prophet continues the unfinished job of the prophet before him*" so either you are not a Muslim as you disbelieve in http://legacy.quran.com/33/40 or you should follow Nostradamus or any later "Prophet" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostradamus

Comment: is nostradamos taked the order from god? or he is just a furtune teller?

Comment: the last person in earth taked order from god with gabriel messanger was muhammed and i just belive muhammed is the last prophet and quran is the last orders of god in the earth.